# Date with microseconds in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date

I have a spreadsheet with lots of dates like this: 17:01:11,356078. I know datenum has not the precision to handle microseconds. Also datevec is not good for that, infact that date became 3.5608e+5 (milliseconds) using it. I need microseconds precision because I have to calculate delta times.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the opportunity to use the latest release R2014b, it includes an overhaul of date and time handling, including new `datetime` objects that handle nanosecond precision.

Prior to that, you're a bit stuck if you need more than millisecond precision, and you may need to implement your own way to store and manipulate your times, rather than rely on the built-in `datenum` and `datestr` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The existing date formats in matlab do not allow for anything smaller than microseconds. Therefore the solution is to avoid these formats.

A comparatively simple way to do this is to split up the numbers. For example, have 1 vector with dates rounded down to the second, and another vector with the fraction of that second. This way you can get a very high precision if needed.

Calculating the difference would then be done by adding the difference in seconds to the difference in the rest. (Using a constant to scale the difference)

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution in my opinion would be to have a function that converts your input string into microseconds, manually and create the timestamp vector.

Unfortunately date/time structures from Matlab don't see lower than miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

the trouble with datenum is that you are limited to the precision of double. If you get rid of the day offset by feeding a date string `0-jan-0000-hrs:mins:secs` datenum is quite capable of resolving femptoseconds. This is only useful if you are not interested in dates, but then again this will be a problem however you convert to a double